# Is there a prefered Linux distro for Android Development?

Tags: android, linux, ipad

I've seen some references to actually using Windows 7, however I expect that a Linux partition on my Laptop would be a better choice.  Other than the Andriod SDK, what other dev tools are "essential" for Android?

I'd also be interested in knowing the system requirements for a reasonable IPad development system and "essentials" software beyond OSX and XCode.  Plus what is the difference in the learning curves for the two platforms.

Comment: Post one question at a time. Your Android and iPad questions are unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse + ADT is everything you need. OS makes no difference.

Comment: Unless you are targeting GoogleTV and want to use the emulator.  The GoogleTV emulator requires linux.  https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator

Answer (score 3):

Depends:

If you're planning on creating your own fork of Android, or committing patches to the Android Open Source Project, then you need either a Linux distro or a case-sensitive partition on OS X.  There are setup instructions for OS X and Ubuntu Linux on the [Getting The Source](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) of the AOSP site.

If you're planning on writing apps for Android, then it really depends on personal preference and development style:

If you're going to use Eclipse + ADT Plugin:  Windows, Mac, and Linux will all work just fine.

Building from the command-line:  You might be better off with OS X or Linux (you don't need to restrict yourself to any single distro) as they tend to have more command-line development tools pre installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is the one that springs to mind simply because getting help is easy and Canonical has been trying to make it easy to use. But as long as you can install a JVM, you're good to go. Remember, Java makes it possible to run apps (Eclipse in this case) without worrying about the OS.